# Properties for classes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writting a code to consolidate data from different sources into one unique structure and I'm going to use classes.

My class logic is going to be X contains Campaigns, which will contain Months and files, Months will contain weeks.

I'm gonna fill three kinds of data inside months and weeks:

1. Real Data, which will come from an OLAP cube
2. Forecast Data, which will come from 200 ish differente files with the same structure.
3. Target Data, to be determined.

My thought then was to build this.

- Main module which will run everything:

---

```
Option Explicit
Private Const Ruta As String = "C:\Users\USER1\Desktop\PdP\"
Sub Main()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = AbrirLibro(Ruta, "MaestroPdP")

    Dim Año As String
    Año = InputBox("Introduce el año para el que deseas la carga.")

    Dim MiPdP As PdP
    MiPdP.CargaP wb, Año
    MiPdP.CargaR wb, Año    

End Sub
Private Function AbrirLibro(Ruta As String, Archivo As String) As Workbook

    Dim Libro As String
    Libro = Dir(Ruta & "*" & Archivo & "*")
    Set AbrirLibro = Workbooks.Open(Ruta & Libro, False, True)

End Function
```

- Main Class module:

---

```
Option Explicit
Private m_Campaña As Object
Property Get Campañas(ByVal Key As String) As Campañas
    With m_Campaña
        If Not .Exists(Key) Then .Add Key, New Campañas
    End With
    Set Campañas = m_Campaña(Key)
End Property
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_Campaña = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set m_Campaña = Nothing
End Sub
Public Property Get Keys() As Variant
    Keys = m_Campaña.Keys
End Property
Public Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = m_Campaña.Count
End Property
Public Sub CargaP(wb As Workbook, Año As String)



End Sub
Public Sub CargaR(wb As Workbook, Año As String)

    FiltrarCuboInicio wb, Año

End Sub
Public Sub CargaT()

End Sub
```

This is fine, but my problem is with the Month class module (and week class module which will be the same with different data):

```
Option Explicit
Private m_Semana As Object
Private P_Recibidas As Single
Private P_TMO As Single
Private P_NDA As Single
Private P_NDS As Single
Private P_UmbralNDS As Single
Private P_Contactos As Single
Private P_TMC As Single
Private P_Gestiones As Single
Private P_TMG As Single
Private P_HorasEfectivas As Single
Private P_HorasTeleop As Single
Private P_Carteras As Single
Private P_JornadaEquivalente As Single
Private P_Formacion As Single
Private P_Descansos As Single
Private P_Otros As Single
Private P_Ausencias As Single
Private P_Vacaciones As Single
Private P_Rotacion As Single
Private P_PorcentajeRotacion As Single
Private P_IneficienciaAjuste As Single
Private P_HorasOcupacion As Single
Private P_HorasRequeridas As Single
Private P_HorasTeleopReq As Single
Private P_HorasContratadas As Single
Private P_AgentesNecesarios As Single
Private P_AgentesNecesariosMañana As Single
Private P_AgentesNecesariosTarde As Single
Private P_AgentesNecesariosNoche As Single
Private P_JornadaSemanal As Single
Private P_DiasDeTrabajo As Long
Private P_AgentesContratados As Single
Private P_AgentesContratadosMañana As Single
Private P_AgentesContratadosTarde As Single
Private P_AgentesContratadosNoche As Single
Private P_AgentesOtrasFunciones As Single
Private P_AgentesOtrasFuncionesMañana As Single
Private P_AgentesOtrasFuncionesTarde As Single
Private P_AgentesOtrasFuncionesNoche As Single
Private P_HorasDisponibles As Single
Private P_AgentesDisponibles As Single
Private P_FaltaExcesoAgentes As Single
Private P_FaltaExcesoAgentesMañana As Single
Private P_FaltaExcesoAgentesTarde As Single
Private P_FaltaExcesoAgentesNoche As Single
Property Get Semanas(ByVal Key As String) As Semanas
    With m_Semana
        If Not .Exists(Key) Then .Add Key, New Semanas
    End With
    Set Semanas = m_Semana(Key)
End Property
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_Semana = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set m_Semana = Nothing
End Sub
Public Property Get Keys() As Variant
    Keys = m_Semana.Keys
End Property
Public Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = m_Semana.Count
End Property
```

This is not even finished, now I need to declare all the R and T variables and build their own procedures to fill and retrieve them.

Is there a way to code this in a simplier or shorter way?

Edit: There are campaigns which will have more than one file, in that case, depending on the variable needs different calculations.

Comment: What are all your `Private` variables for?

Comment: Hello @Tom, later on I'm gonna write all the `Get` and `Let` procedures to store them and use them when needed.

Comment: I suggest that you take all those properties to-be and put them in a dictionary as well.

Comment: @Sam would you care to elaborate with an example please?